# Use IronPython on JetBrains PyCharm

Tags: c#, python, pycharm, ironpython, jetbrains-ide

I want to include some C# code to my python application. I want to use JetBrains Pycharm. So, How do I use IronPython on JetBrains PyCharm? I tried all menus but still couldn't figure it.

Answer (score 3):

(First of all, make sure that you have installed IronPython and have added it to PATH. Then, to use it in Pycharm, do the following:)

1. open Pycharm
2. make your IronPython project
3. You will be give the option to choose your project interpreter. Choose `C:\Program Files\IronPython <version number>\ipy.exe`
4. create your python file(s). You will now be able to run IronPython code.

Comment: Remember, if you are using a custom run/debug configuration, make sure that `C:\Program Files\IronPython <version number>\ipy.exe` is chosen as your python interpreter. Seeing as we picked it as our project interpreter, it should be set on that by default.